# Get location path from use Location hook inside a column renderer from react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap-table

#### Story

I'm creating 2 pages (Summary and Cycles pages) using `react.js`.

On the Summary page, there is a column named `CN` that every item links to the Cycles page.

Summary page has a path `/route/summary/location=abc` and Cycles page has a path `/route/cycle/location=abc/deviceId=4410`

For example, if I click the value from `CN` column in the first row of the table inside the Summary page, I will be redirected to the Cycles page with the path `/route/cycle/location=abc/deviceId=4410`.

In the Summary page, I use https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2 for the table component and I use a `columnRenderer` function inside `columns.js` to render a custom item inside the table like this one:

[image]

#### Question

How can I put the `pathname` (example "abc") to a Link component inside `cnColumnRenderer` function in `columns.js`?

#### Ideal Condition I wanted:

Summary page with the path: `/route/summary/location=abc`

[image: Summary page]

Cycles page with the path: `/route/cycle/location=abc/deviceId=4410`

[image: Cycles page]

#### Actual Condition:

Error because of invalid hook call while rendering the Summary page

[image: Error]

#### My Code:

table code inside Summary page (inside **Summary.js**):

**hint: focus on `columns` variable from './columns' and its implementation**

```js
import React from "react"
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory, {
    PaginationProvider,
    PaginationListStandalone
} from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';

import columns from './columns'

const Summary = () => {    
    const location = useLocation()
    const locationName = location['pathname'].replace('/route/summary/location=', '')
    // console.log('Summary, location:', locationName)
    // example: location = "/route/summary/location=abc" and locationName = "abc"

    // ...some code here...

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container-fluid ppa-route-summary-root">
                <Row>
                    <Col className="col-12">

                        {/* ...some code here... */}

                        {/* TABLE CARD */}
                        <Card>
                            <CardBody>
                                <PaginationProvider
                                    pagination={paginationFactory(paginationOptions)}
                                    keyField='id'
                                    columns={columns}
                                    data={tableData}
                                >
                                    {
                                        ({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => (
                                            <ToolkitProvider
                                                keyField='id'
                                                columns={columns}
                                                data={tableData}
                                                search
                                            >
                                                {
                                                    toolkitProps => (
                                                        <React.Fragment>

                                                            {/* ...some code here... */}

                                                            {/* TABLE ITSELF */}
                                                            <Row>
                                                            <Col xl="12">
                                                                <div className="table-responsive">
                                                                    {
                                                                        isTableLoading ? 
                                                                        <ReactLoading 
                                                                            type={'spin'} 
                                                                            color={'crimson'} 
                                                                            height={'5rem'} 
                                                                            width={'5rem'} 
                                                                            className='table-loading'
                                                                        /> :
                                                                        <BootstrapTable
                                                                            keyField={"id"}
                                                                            responsive
                                                                            bordered={false}
                                                                            striped={false}
                                                                            // defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
                                                                            // selectRow={selectRow}
                                                                            classes={
                                                                                "table align-middle table-nowrap"
                                                                            }
                                                                            headerWrapperClasses={"thead-light"}
                                                                            {...toolkitProps.baseProps}
                                                                            {...paginationTableProps}
                                                                        />
                                                                    }
                                                                </div>
                                                            </Col>
                                                            </Row>

                                                            {/* ...some code here... */}

                                                        </React.Fragment>
                                                    )
                                                }
                                            </ToolkitProvider>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </PaginationProvider>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Summary
```

**columns.js**:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

// IMAGES
import IconLocation from '../../../images/icons/location.svg'

const cnColumnRenderer = (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
    // console.log('columns, cnColumnRenderer:', cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData)
    const deviceVersion = cell.split('-')[1] // example: deviceVersion = "4410"

    const location = useLocation()
    // console.log('Summary columns, location:', location['pathname'])

    // here is the pathname I wanted: "/route/cycle/location=abc" so I can take the "location" path value as below:
    const locationName = location['pathname'].replace('/route/summary/location=', '') // the result is locationName = "abc"
    // then put the locationName inside the Link component

    return(
        <div className='route-summary-cn'>
            <img src={IconLocation} alt='' className='icon-location'/>
            {/* below is the pathname I wanted: "/route/cycle/location=abc/deviceId=4410" */}
            <Link to={`/route/summary/location=${locationName}/deviceId=${row['deviceId']}`}>
                {deviceVersion}
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

const columns = [
    {
        dataField: 'deviceName',
        text: 'CN',
        formatter: cnColumnRenderer,
        sort: true
    },
    {
        dataField: 'convertedTotalCycle',
        text: 'Cycle',
        sort: true,
    },
    // ...some code here...
]

export default columns
```

**Note: let me know if the question is confusing. I will try to update it.**

Comment: React hooks are only valid in React functional components, not in any callbacks, loops, conditional blocks. If you need the location data in the callback it needs to be passed in.

Comment: could you please tell me the code I should use @DrewReese ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React hooks are only valid in React functional components, not in any callbacks, loops, conditional blocks. If you need the location data in the callback it needs to be passed in.

From what I can tell it seems you need to move the `columns.js` code *into* the main component so the `location` values can be closed over in scope.

```
const Summary = () => {    
  const location = useLocation();

  const locationName = location['pathname'].replace('/route/summary/location=', '')
  // example: location = "/route/summary/location=abc" and locationName = "abc"

  // ...some code here...

  const cnColumnRenderer = (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
    // console.log('columns, cnColumnRenderer:', cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData)
    const deviceVersion = cell.split('-')[1] // example: deviceVersion = "4410"

    // then put the locationName inside the Link component

    return(
      <div className='route-summary-cn'>
        <img src={IconLocation} alt='' className='icon-location'/>
        {/* below is the pathname I wanted: "/route/cycle/location=abc/deviceId=4410" */}
        <Link to={`/route/summary/location=${locationName}/deviceId=${row['deviceId']}`}>
          {deviceVersion}
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      dataField: 'deviceName',
      text: 'CN',
      formatter: cnColumnRenderer,
      sort: true
    },
    {
      dataField: 'convertedTotalCycle',
      text: 'Cycle',
      sort: true,
    },
    // ...some code here...
  ];

  return (
    ...
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I thought this also, but if I implement this code, the code for Summary.js will be very long. That's why I try to move some little components outside of Summary.js.
I wonder is there any proper way that I can still declare cnColumnRenderer and columns outside Summary.js? If no, I would use this idea instead.

Comment: @JabalLogian You could turn `cnColumnRenderer` into a factory function that takes a `location` object and returns the formatting function. `columns` would still need to be declared in `Summary` so it can consume `location`. I can add that to my answer if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
If the ```columns``` still need to be declared in ```Summary.js```, I think I will choose the first solution instead.
Thanks a lot, Drew Reese.